# Debian 10で$ make build DEV=trueを実行しますとエラーが出ますので解決したいです。

Tags: linux, bash, debian

お世話になります。
ActivityWatchというManicTimeのようなOSSをDebianにインストールしたいです。
タイムトラッキングのためのOSSです。

以下が実行したコマンドです。nodeとnvmとPythonのインストールはどうにかできました。

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch.git
$ python3 -V
$ node -v
$ nvm -v
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
$ make build DEV=true
```

make build DEV=trueで躓いております。実行しますと下記の結果が出ます。

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'build'.  Stop.
```

どのようにすればインストールできるのでしょうか。ご教授願ます。
下記は公式のドキュメントです。

[ActivityWatchのインストールの公式ドキュメント](https://activitywatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-from-source.html#)

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/226956

Comment: htb様 teratailで満足の行く回答を返していただけなかった場合は、マルチポストを今後もさせていただきます。
しかし、私もマルチポスト時のマナーを存じませんでしたので、申し訳ございませんでした。
今後はマルチポストをするときはきちんと申し出てリンクを貼った上で行おうと思っております。
なお、teratailもスタックオーバーフローもマルチポストを禁止していないと明記されていますので、そこはご容赦いただければと思います。

Comment: 私は質問者さんに対して何も申し上げていませんし、特に気にしないでください。インターネット上の同じリソースにリンクを張っただけです。

Comment: htb様 そうでしたか、勝手に被害妄想をしてしまい大変申し訳ございませんでした。。
私に配慮をしてくださっていたのですね、ありがとうございます^_^

Comment: いいえ、今後回答されるであろう人に配慮したまでです。

Comment: htb様 そうでしたか。私にとっても助かりましたので感謝いたします^_^

Comment: マルチポストについてはどのサイトでも強い禁止にこそしていないものの、いわゆるネチケットとしては避けられる傾向になります。止む無く他のサイトに同じ投稿を行う場合には、その事を (自ら) 明言して欲しいです。/ 回答がダブった場合、回答を付けた側は無駄な労力を使うことになりますし、質問した側も「それは別のサイトで聞いた」という自体になるのはお互いに不幸です。

Comment: cubick様 ネチケットを私に教えていただき感謝です。次の質問からはマルチポスト先のリンクをお貼りしております。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git clone` した後、`activitywatch` ディレクトリに移動してから `make` を実行してください。

```
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch.git
$ ls                  ## activitywatch ディレクトリがあるか確認
$ cd activitywatch
$ make build DEV=true
```

表示されているエラーは "`build` という(makeの)ルールが見つからない" という内容ですが
これは Makefile に記述されているので、該当の Makefile が存在するディレクトリに移動してから
`make` コマンドを実行する必要があります。

Comment: `$ cd activitywatch`を実行してから`$ make build DEV=true`を実行したのですが、次のコメントに記述するエラーが出てきました。

Comment: `$ make build DEV=true
if [ -e "aw-core/.git" ]; then \
        echo "Submodules seem to already be initialized, continuing..."; \
else \
        git submodule update --init --recursive; \
fi
Submodules seem to already be initialized, continuing...
make --directory=aw-core build DEV=true
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-core'
pip3 install --editable . -r requirements.txt
make[1]: pip3: Command not found
make[1]: *** [Makefile:10: build] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/aw-core'
make: *** [Makefile:33: build] Error 2`

Comment: @Yusuke_O_kaiy まずはエラーメッセージを読んでみてください。`pip3: Command not found` と書かれています。Pythonをどのようにインストールしたのかを確認し、`pip3` がインストールされ使えるようになっているか確かめてください。

Comment: > nekketsuuu様 承知致しました。アドバイス感謝です。

Comment: > nekketsuuu様 pip3をインストールし使えるようにしまして、`make build`を実行しましたところ、新たなエラーが出ました。新たなエラーは別の質問という形で投稿させていただきました。親身なご回答感謝いたします。